# api to query iphone info by serial number or imei

Tags: iphone

I have an app need to query iPhone hardware parameters, such as model, color, size of storage, active date, given serial number or IMEI. Is that possible? Is there some sort of HTTP API I can call?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not all possible and especially not via HTTP API.

In a native app you will be able to get the model, screen size, size of storage, current date  and os version. But any unique identifier are not accessible any more.

Comment: However, My app is not native. And now in the apple website, it is impossible to query such detail information any more. Stuff thing.

Comment: Well you will not be able to get more that the iOS version from the HTTP headers and the screen size via Javascript. All the other thing will not be possible.